# Template specialization requires duplicate parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I want to specialize template based on parameter `which`, but if I remove `template < bool which2 = which >` compilation fails. Why?
How to avoid repetition?

```
#include <iostream>

template < typename T, bool which >
class Node {
    T key;
public:
    template < bool which2 = which >
    typename std::enable_if < which2 == false, bool >::type operator < ( const Node & second );
    template < bool which2 = which >
    typename std::enable_if < which2 == true, bool >::type operator < ( const Node & second );

    Node ( ) {
        (*this) < (*this);
    }
};

template < class T, bool which >
template < bool which2 >
typename std::enable_if < which2 == false, bool >::type Node < T, which >::operator < ( const Node & second ) {
    std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

template < class T, bool which >
template < bool which2 >
typename std::enable_if < which2 == true, bool >::type Node < T, which >::operator < ( const Node & second ) {
    std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

template < typename T, bool which >
class BH {
    Node < T, which > node;
};

int main ( ) {
    BH < int, true > aa;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is [this your issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41091480)

Comment: Yes, if there will be need to specialize some template on int type, then there will be a lot of duplicate code.