# Given a function parameter of type Container<T>::Iterator, how do I achieve a specific overload for certain kinds of T?

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-passing, fft, c++17

I've been meddling with signal processing on my free time, and I'm writing my own DSP library as a learning exercise. I've written a function which computes the discrete fourier transform of a vector. There are two overloads of the function: one for `const std::vector<float> &`, and another for `std::vector<std::complex<float>>`.

I'd like to make this more generic. Instead of a vector, the function should accept a pair of generic random access iterators. The compiler should then deduce from the iterators whether it's complex or real valued data and select the right overload.

---

This should give you an idea,

```
//compute the discrete fourier transform in-place for a complex valued input
template<template<typename T> class Container, typename T, class RandomAccessIt>
void fft(
        typename Container<std::complex<T>>::RandomAccessIt first,
        typename Container<std::complex<T>>::RandomAccessIt last
    )
{
    ...
}

//calculate the discrete fourier transform for a real valued input
template<template<typename T> class Container1,
         template<std::complex<T>> class Container2,
         typename T,
         class RandomAccessIt1,
         class RandomAccessIt2>
void fft(
        typename Container1<T>::RandomAccessIt1 first,
        typename Container1<T>::RandomAccessIt1 last,
        typename Container2<std::complex<T>>::RandomAccessIt2 out_first
    )
{
    ...
    fft(...); //call the complex version
    ...        
}
```

but as you can see I don't really know what I'm doing with templates. How could I get that to work? If it isn't possible as-is, why?

---

#### EDIT:

I like the `if constexpr` -approach the most, as it solves the issue quite elegantly

```
template<typename T>
struct is_complex_t : public std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_complex_t<std::complex<T>> : public std::true_type {};

template<typename RandomAccessIt>
void fft(RandomAccessIt first, RandomAccessIt last)
{
    using Number_t = typename std::iterator_traits<RandomAccessIt>::value_type;
    if constexpr(!is_complex_t<Number_t>::value)
    {
        //math trickery to transform the real input data to complex-valued data
        ...
    }
    ... //the FFT itself
    if constexpr(!is_complex_t<Number_t>::value)
    {
        //math trickery to properly format the frequency domain data
        ...
    }
}
```

That said, I have since realized that as the two overloads have a different number of parameters, **I don't even need any clever metaprogramming**:

```
//compute the discrete fourier transform in-place for a complex valued input
template<typename RandomAccessIt>
void fft(RandomAccessIt first, RandomAccessIt last)
{
    //...
}

//calculate the discrete fourier transform for a real valued input
template<typename RandomAccessIt1, typename RandomAccessIt2>
void fft(
        RandomAccessIt1 first, RandomAccessIt1 last,
        RandomAccessIt2 out_first
    )
{
    //...
    //fft(...); //call the complex version
    //...
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`iterator::value_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits)?

Comment: And template argument deduction will fail in your code.

Comment: with `container<T>::type`, `T` is non deducible, you should take `typename Iterator` directly.

Comment: I know of `iterator::value_type` and `std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type `, I just can't figure out how to use it here.

Comment: @jms As others have mentions, take an iterator type as your template arguments rather than a container template template.

Comment: As of `c++17` you can write `template<typename> typename` to stay consistent with your type parameter declarations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, just drop the Container and T template parameters, and take just the iterator type; this is what all of the standard library algorithms (e.g. in `<algorithm>`) do. Then use [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) to get `T` as the iterator's `value_type`.

Now, for your specialization, you can use one of:

- `std::enable_if_t`
- tagged dispatch
- constexpr-if - so you'll have the same function with two scopes for the two cases.

In this question:

[if constexpr instead of tag dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46169709/if-constexpr-instead-of-tag-dispatch)

You'll see an example of how to use the second option (tagged dispatch) in the question, and an example of how to convert that to constexpr-if in one of the answers.