# Disable a member function based on class template parameter value

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, metaprogramming, enable-if

I would like to have a class which disables/enables member functions based on the value of a template parameter to a class. I have the following:

```
enum MyType{ type1, type2 };
template <MyType type>
class Test{
    public:
        enum TestTraits{ testType = type };
        template <typename T>
        constexpr bool func(SomethingElse<T> else)
        {
           if(testType == type1) return false;
           // some logic that would return true or false
        }
};
```

I would basically like to make it a compile time check instead of a runtime check, and that its not even an option for the client to call it if possible. I'm sure the solution is enable_if, but when I see that, it seems like it requires the enable_if to decide the return type or one of the function parameters

Comment: essentially, yes

Comment: How many different permutations is it going to be?  For a simple example of 2 like this, you could just specialize the class for the two different options.

Comment: just two types, and I have implemented that solution before, but there are a handful of functions that differ within. I was hoping I could get away with just "one" class

Comment: What you really need is [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If), but that is a C++17 feature.  Otherwise you can have multiple overloads and use SFINAE like jork just answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you'll want one of the following:

`enable_if` in the return type of the function that you wan't to enable/disable
(you can still have the function return `bool`):

```
    template <typename T>
    constexpr typename std::enable_if<type != type1, bool>::type 
    func(SomethingElse<T>)
    {
          return true;
    }
```

or a static assert declaration:

```
    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool func(SomethingElse<T>)
    {
         static_assert(type != type1, "can't call this with type1...");
         return true;
    }
```

Third option is moving the function that are to be disabled in a base class. Then specialize that base for `type1` and leave it empty:

```
template<MyType mytype>
struct SpecialStuff {
    bool func();
};

template<>
struct SpecialStuff<type1> {
};

template<MyType mytype>
struct CommonStuff : private SpecialStuff<mytype> {
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure of `SomethingElse`'s intent, so consider this pseudocode...

Comment: So i get the following compile error using the first approach: `error: need typename before std::enable_if because std::enable_if is a dependent scope... any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, forgot a `typename`, as the error said... Fixed :)

Comment: yep, sorry about that, forgot about that little issue

Comment: actually, when I attempt this on a type1 object I get the following error: `no type named 'type' in struct std::enable_if<>` any thoughts?

Comment: The condition that you check in `enable_if` needs to depend on a template parameter somehow, otherwise there is no SFINAE but a hard error instead. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401716/selecting-a-member-function-using-different-enable-if-conditions) for a possible solution.

Comment: gotcha, got that working. so I if i want to add a third type, and a second "overload" function that handles that type I have to specify some third template parameter to make them different?

Comment: Not sure as I don't how you've setup so far. Show your code and we'll see.