# Generic lambdas, overloading, std::is_invocable and SFINAE - different behavior among GCC and Clang

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++17, sfinae

#### Problem

I wrote a convoluted piece of template code that can be compiled [with GCC 8.2.1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KlxvED1Qt5dXWJL6), but not [with Clang 7.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FufiSx2clKKdvU0i) (code and error links).

I think this might be an implication of [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015938/overload-resolution-behaviour-difference-between-gcc-and-clang-sfinae), but I am unable to see it.

#### Motivation

I am writing a class, which I would like to be constructible with two callables of different types, but also with one of them omitted, i.e.:

```
my_class(callable_1);
my_class(callable_2);
my_class(callable_1, callable_2);
```

That should go without problems. But, why not allow `callable_1` and `callable_2` to be function templates (or functors with `operator()` template). That is, I would like to have this (or at least initially wanted):

```
my_class([](auto arg) {});
my_class([](auto arg) {});
my_class([](auto arg) {}, [](auto arg) {});
```

As, you can see, both callables unfortunately have the same signature, so we need to disambiguate between them somehow. The first approach I could think of (and the one this question is about) is to add a "tag" parameter to one of the unary overloads:

```
my_class([](auto arg) {});
my_class([](auto arg) {}, callable_2_tag());
my_class([](auto arg) {}, [](auto arg) {});
```

This, to me, looks acceptable, but I have come up with better solutions:

- use the tag (optional if not ambiguous) in the second callable's signature (the last parameter or return type)
- make the second constructor overload into a differently named non-member or `static` member function

**Still, I would like to know, why there is the difference in behavior among the two compilers with my initial approach and which one is correct** (or whether both are).

---

#### Code:

I have translated the constructor overloads into regular `my_class` function overloads for simplicity.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// parameter types for callbacks and the tag class
struct foo { void func1() {} };
struct bar { void func2() {} };
struct bar_tag {};

// callable checks
template <typename Func>
static constexpr bool is_valid_func_1_v = std::is_invocable_r_v<void, Func, foo>;

template <typename Func>
static constexpr bool is_valid_func_2_v = std::is_invocable_r_v<void, Func, bar>;

// default values
static constexpr auto default_func_1 = [](foo) {};
static constexpr auto default_func_2 = [](bar) {};

// accepting callable 1
template <typename Func1, std::enable_if_t<is_valid_func_1_v<Func1>>* = nullptr>
void my_class(Func1&& func_1)
{
    my_class(std::forward<Func1>(func_1), default_func_2);
}

// accepting callable 1
template <typename Func2, std::enable_if_t<is_valid_func_2_v<Func2>>* = nullptr>
void my_class(Func2&& func_2, bar_tag)
{
    my_class(default_func_1, std::forward<Func2>(func_2));
}

// accepting both
template <
    typename Func1, typename Func2,
    // disallow Func2 to be deduced as bar_tag
    // (not even sure why this check did not work in conjunction with others,
    // even with GCC)
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<Func2, bar_tag>>* = nullptr,
    std::enable_if_t<is_valid_func_1_v<Func1> &&
                     is_valid_func_2_v<Func2>>* = nullptr>
void my_class(Func1&& func_1, Func2&& func_2)
{
    std::forward<Func1>(func_1)(foo());
    std::forward<Func2>(func_2)(bar());
}

int main()
{
    my_class([](auto foo) { foo.func1(); });
    my_class([](auto bar) { bar.func2(); }, bar_tag());
}
```

For Clang, this will result in:

```
error: no member named 'func1' in 'bar'
my_class([](auto foo) { foo.func1(); });
                        ~~~ ^
...
note: in instantiation of variable template specialization
'is_valid_func_2_v<(lambda at prog.cc:41:14)>' requested here
template <typename Func2, std::enable_if_t<is_valid_func_2_v<Func2>>* = nullptr>
                                           ^
```

What happened here? **Substitution failure is an error?**

**Edit:** It was completely ignorant from me to think that an error inside a predicate of `std::enable_if` will be silenced as well... That is **not** a substitution failure.

#### Fix:

If I put the SFINAE as a function parameter, Clang handles it well. **I do not know why deferring the check from the template argument deduction stage to the overload resolution stage makes the difference.**

```
template <typename Func2>
void my_class(Func2&& func_2, bar_tag,
              std::enable_if_t<is_valid_func_2_v<Func2>>* = nullptr)
{
    my_class(default_func_1, std::forward<Func2>(func_2));
}
```

---

All in all, I have dived into genericity probably more than I should have with my knowledge and now I am paying for it. So what is it that I am missing? Attentive reader might notice some side questions popping up, but I do not want an answer for all of them. Lastly, I am sorry if a much simpler MCVE could have been made.

Comment: Does it work if you call it with `my_class([](foo f) { f.func1(); })`? I can't tell from the cppreference description what the expected behaviour is of `is_invocable_r` in your existing case. In fact, I'd have expected the compile error either way.

Comment: @JohnIlacqua [Yes](https://wandbox.org/permlink/njwjR30spUV040c0), with both compilers, and even for `bar`, if we make `bar_tag` optional.

Comment: With g++ head 9.0.0 2018 (tried in Wandbox) I get the same error as clang++; not an expert but I suppose that clang++ and more recent g++ are correct.

Comment: I think the way you're using `is_invokable_r` isn't quite correct SFINAE. See this: https://godbolt.org/z/cYtb8p. I think the only reason any compiler would accept it is if it's not actually instantiating the `is_valid_func_2` on your `foo` lambda.

Comment: Interesting question. [This](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/NlncKp) is a simpler program to (possibly) reproduce your problem.

Comment: Anyway, I asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53024903/5376789).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, you're not quite using SFINAE correctly - if you ever try to call `std::is_invocable_r_v<void, Func, bar>;` with `Func == decltype([](auto foo) { foo.func1(); }` you will get a compiler error, as the auto in the lambda is deduced to `bar` and then tries to call `func1()` on it. If your lambda didn't use auto and instead had the actual type as the parameter (i.e. `foo`, so you can't invoke it with a `bar`), `is_invocable_r_v` would return false and the SFINAE would work.

Comment: As a side note, my guess as to why gcc is compiling it is that it's probably ignoring the overload due to having a different number of parameters before it even looks at the `enable_if`s.

Comment: Yes, this is the core of the problem. If you could find a standard paragraph allowing compilers unspecified behavior concerning ruling out the overloads (if one exists), that would be the perfect answer.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have a copy of the standard to consult (and it's also almost 11pm), so I'm not able to find and add a reference at the moment. I don't even know if it is allowed by the standard - someone else mentioned that it doesn't compile with gcc-9, so perhaps it was wrong and they fixed it.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, and excuse me keeping the question open for a while to attract more readers and their thoughts.