# Template Argument Deduction Failure and Function Parameters/Arguments Mismatch

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction

Consider the following program:

```
template <class T> struct A { using X = typename T::X; };
template <class T, typename A<T>::X* = nullptr> void f(T, int);
void f(...);
template <class T> void g(T, int, typename A<T>::X* = nullptr); // #
void g(...);

int main() {
  // f(0, nullptr); // error
  g(0, nullptr); // ok       
}
```

`g(0, nullptr)` compiles while `f(0, nullptr)` does not (tested under GCC trunk and Clang trunk on [Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/2mxKg-)). It seems that during the template argument deduction process of `#`, the compiler does not instantiate `A<int>` when it finds the argument `nullptr` does not match the parameter `int`. Where does the standard specify this behavior?

Comment: MSVC fails on both. EDG compiles both. :(

Comment: So basically this is a SFINAE question, and the core issue is which part of template instantiation is covered under "Substitution Failure". Does the unnamed defaulted template argument in `f` cause a substitution failure?

Comment: @MSalters I think neither is substitution failure (I use `A<T>::X` rather than `T::X` to try to avoid substitution failure). If you delete the `int` parameter and call it like `g(0)`, then both GCC and Clang reject the code.

Comment: My g++ (6.3.0) compiles both; my clang++ (3.8.1)  fail on both. Gosh.

Comment: @xskxzr: That sounds reasonable - substitution failure would reduce the overload sets to just `f(...)` and `g(...)` respectively, which means any form would be acceptable. That's the point of SFINAE - it silently removes potential overloads that would be ill-formed.

Answer (score 4):

This is [CWG1391](https://wg21.link/cwg1391):

> If deduction succeeds for all parameters that contain
>   *template-parameters* that participate in template argument deduction, and all template arguments are explicitly specified, deduced, or
>   obtained from default template arguments, remaining parameters are
>   then compared with the corresponding arguments. For each remaining
>   parameter `P` with a type that was non-dependent before substitution
>   of any explicitly-specified template arguments, if the corresponding
>   argument `A` cannot be implicitly converted to `P`, deduction fails.

Comment: So do you mean it is a bug that `f(0, nullptr)` is rejected?

Comment: So this step should be performed before substitution of deduced template parameter? But for `f` substitution must be performed in the second template parameter to get its argument. So this paragraph would not apply to `f`. So I expected this paragraph not to apply to `f` even in [this case](https://godbolt.org/z/8aefh1). But both gcc and clang accept this code. Is the substitution of deduced template arguments performed in two steps: before application of this paragraph, substitution is performed in the template parameter; after this paragraph, substitution is performed in the function type?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that you are bitten by [DR #1844](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1844). In [temp.deduct]/8 it states:

> If a substitution results in an invalid type or expression, type deduction fails. An invalid type or expression is one that would be ill-formed, with a diagnostic required, if written using the substituted arguments. [ Note: If no diagnostic is required, the program is still ill-formed.
>   Access checking is done as part of the substitution process. — end note] Only invalid types and expressions in the immediate context of the function type, its template parameter types, and its explicit-specifier can result in a deduction failure. [ Note: The substitution into types and expressions can result in effects such as the instantiation of class template specializations and/or function template specializations, the generation of implicitly-defined functions, etc. Such effects are not in the “immediate context” and can result in the program being ill-formed. — end note ]

The problem here is that "immediate context" is not really given a definition, leading to variance among compilers.

Comment: I think there is no reason for a specific compiler to treat `A<T>::X` in `f` as not an immediate context, but to treat that in `g` as an immediate context. So why is there a difference between the behaviors for `f` and `g`?